# PHP MySQL Password Reset Form not executing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple reset password form where the user enters their username, email address, a new password and confirms the new password. However, nothing happens when I run the page. Below is the form that I'm using as well as the PHP script.

FORM:

```
 <form method="POST" action="password.php">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Enter your Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="60" name="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>Enter your UserName</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="30" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your new password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" size="30" name="newpassword"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>Re-enter your new password:</td>
   <td><input type="password" size="30" name="confirmnewpassword"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Update Password">
    </form>
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php require_once('Connections/register.php'); ?>
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmnewpassword = $_POST['confirmnewpassword'];

// Redirect links for when password reset is successful or not.
$MM_passwordResetSuccess = "password-updated.php";
$MM_passwordResetFailed = "reset-password.php";


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE 
username='$username' AND email='$email'");
        if(!$result)
        {
        echo "The username or email you entered does not exist";
        }

        if($password == $confirmnewpassword)
        $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE register SET password='$password' where 

 username='$username' AND email='$email'");
        if($sql)
        {
            header("Location: " . $MM_passwordResetSuccess );
        //echo "Congratulations You have successfully changed your password";
        }
       else
        {
            header("Location: ". $MM_passwordResetFailed );
       //echo "Passwords do not match";
       }
      ?>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you have error_reporting switched on? put `error_reporting (E_ALL);` as your first line.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: this `$_POST['password'];` should be `$_POST['newpassword'];` - so you get an `'UNDEFINED INDEX ERROR'`

Comment: _BUT_: 1st: __never__ store plain passwords into your database. 2nd: use prepared statements. 3rd: you need to ask for the _old_ password too.

Comment: Hi Jeff, no I don't. I'm new to PHP. Rather than updating the password in the database it's failing every time, any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: read my second comment. that's what's wrong!

Comment: Jeff thank you so much that worked! Life saver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this input element `<td><input type="password" size="30" name="newpassword"></td>` with name 'newpassword', but then you try to get `$password = $_POST['password']` - 'password' only.
So change that to `$password = $_POST['newpassword'];`

*BUT*:
1st: **never** store plain passwords into your database. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`
2nd: Use prepared statements. Now this script is very unsecure.
3rd: You need to ask for the *old* password too.
4th: You should check if you got values first, so do a

```
if(!isset($_POST['email']) { 
   // show an error, exit script
   echo "ERROR"
}
```

for every post-variable. Otherwise you could get an error (as you did now).
5th: Switch on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking for the form submission ..

Also, you should add a name to the input field

Like this :

```
<p><input name="reset" type="submit" value="Update Password">
```

PHP file :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['reset'])){

//Your php code


}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the header as follow :`header("Location: password-updated.php" );` and `header("Location: reset-password.php");` as it is simplest ways to use header function. Also change `$password = $_POST['password'];` to `$password = $_POST['newpassword'];`

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong in keeing the header redirects modular!